# How to Convert NSMutableArray objects to const char in xcode

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode4, nsmutablearray

To develop a calculator in xcode I am using a c class for converting infix to postfix expression and its evaluation. But I have an NSString in my View controller class and I need to pass this NSString to a C class where the conversion and evaluation happens. How can I do this?

Comment: Where does the NSMutableArray that you mention in your question's title come into it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert NSString to cString. It can be done by

```
[str UTF8String]
```

Comment: my requirement is suppose my string is s=@"11+12".Then in C class when it takes first char it should get 11 but now what getting is 1.How to tackle this problem

Comment: After getting the string you have to parse it using your own logic like split the string with respect to char "+" to get 11 and 12.

Comment: I have these 11,+ and 12 in an NSMutable array.Now how can i convert this or pass to c class where that function receives a const char datatype.

Comment: you can see the code in this link..please do checkhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/13265822/rpn-calculator-for-iphone

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an `NSMutableArray` containing `NSString` objects, and you want to convert this to a C array containing C strings, you need to allocate memory for a C array of `char *` of suitable size (e.g., count of the `NSMutableArray` + maybe 1 extra if you want a `NULL` terminator for the array, otherwise you need to pass along the array's element count everywhere). Then for each element of the `NSMutableArray`, populate the corresponding index in the C array with the C string returned by `UTF8String` of the `NSString` object.

Note that the C strings returned by `UTF8String` are “autoreleased”, so if you need to keep them around for longer than the current autorelease context, you need to duplicate them (e.g., `strdup`) and then `free` them (and the C array, which you need to `free` in any case) after you're done with them.

For example:

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printCStringsInArray(const char **arr) {
    int i = 0;
    while (*arr) { printf("%d: %s\n", i++, *arr++); }
}

int main () {
    const char **carr;
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSMutableArray *arr;
        const char **p;

        arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"11", @"+", @"12", nil];
        p = carr = malloc(sizeof(*carr) * ([arr count] + 1));
        for (NSString *s in arr) {
            *p++ = strdup([s UTF8String]);
        }
        *p = NULL; // mark the end of carr
    }
    printCStringsInArray(carr);
    { // free the C strings and array
        const char **p = carr;
        while (*p) { free(*p++); };
        free(carr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
0: 11
1: +
2: 12
```

**edit**: Of course if you just want to call some C function taking individual strings as `const char *` from your otherwise Objective-C code, you don't need to do anything this complicated, just convert each string on the fly with `UTF8String` and use the `NSMutableArray` for iteration, etc. But then one might wonder what it is that you can do with C strings that you couldn't do directly with `NSString`s.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy because you can use NSString's UTF8String method, but you have to handle memory allocation: allocate a block to contain the string.Choose if to wrap it into a NSData so that it will be released automatically when out of the pool block, or if to free it manually:

```
@autoreleasepool
    {
        NSArray* strings= @[ @"Hello", @"Hey" ]; // Your strings
        // This could be also a NSMutableArray if you need it
        NSMutableArray* cstrings=[NSMutableArray new];  // C strings
        for(NSString* string in strings)  // Iterate over all the strings
        {
            const char* temp=[string UTF8String];  // Get C string
            const unsigned long length=strlen(temp);  // Allocate memory for it
            char* string=(char*)malloc((length+1)*sizeof(char));
            strcpy(string,temp); // Copy it
            // Store it inside NSData
            [cstrings addObject: [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy: string length: (length+1)*sizeof(char)]];
        }
    }
```